# How to create an SSIS Foreach ADO Enumerator programmatically with C#

Tags: c#, ssis

I'm trying to use C# to build my package, and add a `Foreach ADO Enumerator` task to an SSIS package programmatically. However, I can't work out how to set the Source to my ADO Object and Map the ADO Object fields to the Variable Mappings.

**Edit:**

I have this so far. It creates the task ok, and I'm adding the variables.  So I think I just need to be able to set the ADO Object Source Variable, but can't work it out.

```
Executables executables = pkg.Executables;
ForEachLoop forEachLoop = executables.Add("STOCK:ForEachLoop") as ForEachLoop;

forEachLoop.Name = group.ToString();
PrecedenceConstraint constraint = pkg.PrecedenceConstraints.Add(mainPipe, forEachLoop);

// Create a VariableMappings and VariableMapping objects.
ForEachVariableMappings forEachVariableMappings = forEachLoop.VariableMappings;
ForEachVariableMapping forEachVariableMapping = forEachVariableMappings.Add();

forEachVariableMapping.VariableName = @"User::ClientName";
forEachVariableMapping.ValueIndex = 0;


ForEachVariableMapping forEachVariableMapping2 = forEachVariableMappings.Add();

forEachVariableMapping2.VariableName = @"User::LinkedServer";
forEachVariableMapping2.ValueIndex = 1;


ForEachEnumeratorInfo forEachEnumeratorInfo = app.ForEachEnumeratorInfos["Foreach ADO Enumerator"];
ForEachEnumeratorHost forEachEnumeratorHost = forEachEnumeratorInfo.CreateNew();
forEachEnumeratorHost.CollectionEnumerator = true;
```

Comment: What code do you have so far? Why are you building a package in C#?

Comment: the reason I am building the package in c # is because I need to create many packages all very similar, based on parameters from a console app

Comment: There's something called BIML that may help with that.

Comment: I didnt know about BIML it may well help, but in the mean time any ideas how to add the Ado source object? Thsnks

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking how you can set the "ADO object source variable" in the Foreach ADO Enumerator configuration.

You are pretty close. The foreach loop container also behaves a little like a Task, in the sense that it hosts an InnerObject. This InnerObject is set to the appropriate Enumerator as needed.

In your code, you have created the [ForEachEnumeratorHost](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.foreachenumeratorhost.aspx) object. If you looked at the documentation, you can see that it has an InnerObject property. You need to access the InnerObject and cast it to exact type of Enumerator you want. In this case, you should cast it to an object of type [ForEachADOEnumerator](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.enumerators.ado.foreachadoenumerator.aspx). Once you cast it, the cast object can then expose to you the properties such as Type, DataObjectVariable which can be used to configure the Ado Enumerator.

Also, to access the ForEachADOEnumerator object, you need to add a reference to the Microsoft.SqlServer.ForEachADOEnumerator.dll

So just do this:

```
// cast the inner object as ForEachADOEnumerator 
        ForEachADOEnumerator adoEnum = forEachEnumeratorHost.InnerObject as ForEachADOEnumerator;

        // then access the properties and set them
        // set the variable
        adoEnum.DataObjectVariable = "User::MyVar";

        // set the enumeration mode
        adoEnum.Type = ADOEnumerationType.EnumerateRowsInFirstTable;

        // finally...
        forEachLoop.ForEachEnumerator = forEachEnumeratorHost;
```

As a general guideline, I would encourage you to look at the msdn documentation for all these respective classes; make manual changes to the ssis package and observe the changes in the xml and tie them back to the different classes, properties and methods from msdn documentation. Pretty soon, you will get a hang for how to develop packages programmatically.